# Particular website loading slow on WebBrowser control in C#

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

When I load the following page in IE9 on Windows 7 then it loads fine. But when I load the same page in WebBrowser control in C#, it takes 10+ seconds to load. Why is that?

http://www.edu.gov.on.ca/eng/sift/index.asp

I am simply using **webbrowser.Navigate** with this URL as parameter.

**EDIT**

Ok after little investigation I found out that it could be due to page size. The combined page size with images and scripts (when I save it in IE9 as "File --> Save As") becomes 596KB.
But if WebBrowser itself is actually IE9 then why loading in IE9 is faster but in WebBrowser control is slower?

Comment: It takes only a second when I try it.  You however have to set the ScriptErrorsSuppressed property to True, it has several Javascript buglets.  Maybe enough to slow it down, not sure.

Comment: Yes I have already set it to true. I closed Visual Studio and then tried again and now it is loading faster, probably takes 2,3 seconds.

Comment: "But if WebBrowser itself is actually IE9 then why loading in IE9 is faster but in WebBrowser control is slower?" One reason would be because the WebBrowser is not using the IE9 engine.  Even if it were you don't indicate which version of the .net framework you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's taking about 12 secs on Chrome, IE, Firefox, Safari and Opera here. Tested right now. 

Are you **100% sure** that there is **no** caching on the way?
Propably your IE is caching pages (Temporary Internet Files) and the C# WebBrowser is not using that cache, though I've never used this control to say it for sure...

All tests here were made with a clean cache, so it will always fetch the whole page from the server.

I'm testing this from Brazil using two ISP links (10Mbps 10% guarantee coaxial + 1Mbps 50% guarantee fiber).

Comment: I closed Visual Studio and then tried again and now it is loading faster, probably takes 2,3 seconds. I think I need to check my application may be over time the WebBrowser control becomes lagging due to some memory problem?

Comment: @Ali - Unlikely..That control is not new, its been tested, its more likely the website is simply slow.